# Joining two tables to display data relative to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am new to the types of SQL joins and have a very basic issue.

I have two tables:

The Users table

| id | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | San Francisco |
| 2 | Moscow |
| 3 | London |
| 4 | Washington |

The cities table

| city | country |
| --- | --- |
| Moscow | Russia |
| San Francisco | USA |
| Washington | USA |
| London | England |

I am selecting the id from the users table and matching it up with its respective country in the cities table. I want to produce the below table using an SQL select statement:

| id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | Russia |
| 3 | England |
| 4 | USA |

So far I have written the following, but I have no idea where to continue from there (or if this is even a correct start) as SQL joins confuse me slightly.

```
SELECT users.city, cities.city FROM users INNER JOIN cities ON
```

Comment: Although there's a problem with storing the city name in the `users` table: What about places that share the same city name? For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_(disambiguation)), _London, Kentucky_ vs. _London, England_.

Comment: The spelling of "San Francisco" was inconsistent in the orginal version. Was that the ***actual*** error (caused by a typo)? If not, how would it affect the result? Could an error-tolerant SQL query be written?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple join:

```
select u.*, c.country
from users u
inner join cities c on c.city = u.city
```